# Table with table-layout: fixed; and how to make one column wider

Tags: html, css, xhtml

So I have a table with this style:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Which makes all columns to be of the same width. I would like to have one column (the first one) to be wider and then rest of the columns to occupy the remaining width of the table with equal widths.

How to achieve that?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ddd;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table th, table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table td.wideRow, table th.wideRow {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table class="CalendarReservationsBodyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="97">Rezervovane auta</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="corner wideRow">Auto</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">0</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">1</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">2</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">3</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">4</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">5</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">6</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">7</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">8</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">9</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">10</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">11</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">12</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">13</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">14</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">15</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">16</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">17</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">18</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">19</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">20</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">21</th>
      <th class="odd" colspan="4">22</th>
      <th class="" colspan="4">23</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="alignRight wideRow">KE-260 FC - Octavia combi</td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td colspan="16" class="highlighted borderLeft" title="Richard Knop">
        Richard Knop
      </td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td colspan="14" class="highlighted" title="Richard Knop">
        Richard Knop
      </td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=" borderLeft"></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
      <td class=""></td>
      <td class="odd"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6p9K3/

Notice the first column, I want it to be `300px` wide.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could just give the first cell (therefore column) a width and have the rest default to `auto`

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
}
td+td {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>150px</td>
    <td>equal</td>
    <td>equal</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

or alternatively the "proper way" to get column widths might be to use the [`col` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-COL) itself

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.wide {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col span="1" class="wide">
    <tr>
      <td>150px</td>
      <td>equal</td>
      <td>equal</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yea seems to - certainly the `col` technique does anyway: **[see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/HSVae/) - and with the colspan method you could then go on a set other column widths as required too

Comment: If you have a `thead` the width should be set on its `th`

Comment: Does not work, if there is a table caption available: `<table><caption>...</caption><tbody>....</tbody></table>`

Comment: Just use `td:first-of-type { width: 150px; }`. No need for two selectors. Also keep in mind that the first row of the table with `table-layout: fixed` determines the width.

Comment: @ZachSaucier makes a really important point here that's easy to overlook. You can specify what row for the browser to start looking at widths by setting table-layout: fixed to that specific row. Everywhere else I saw only said "it starts looking at the first cell".

Answer (score 62):

The important thing of table-layout: fixed is that the column widths are determined by the first row of the table.

So

if your table structure is as follow (standard table structure)

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th> First column </th>
          <th> Second column </th>
          <th> Third column </th>        
      </tr>
  </thead>

   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td> First column </td>
          <td> Second column </td>
          <td> Third column </td>        
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

if you would like to give a width to second column then

```
<style> 
    table{
        table-layout:fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }

    table tr th:nth-child(2){
       width: 60%;
     }

</style>
```

Please look that we style the th not the td.

Comment: great tip- table tr th:nth-child(4)

Answer (score 9):

Are you creating a very large table (hundreds of rows and columns)?  If so, `table-layout: fixed;` is a good idea, as the browser only needs to read the first row in order to compute and render the entire `table`, so it loads faster.

But if not, I would suggest dumping `table-layout: fixed;` and changing your css as follows:

```
table th, table td{
border: 1px solid #000;
width:20px;  //or something similar   
}

table td.wideRow, table th.wideRow{
width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6p9K3/1/

Comment: That does not work properly. Look at 8,9,10,11 columns, they are too narrow.

Comment: gotcha. You can fix that by placing the content in the `td` that spans the four `th`s like so: `<div style="width:80px;">Richard Knop</div>`  Set the `width` to the sum of all the individual `td`s.   See here http://jsfiddle.net/6p9K3/2/

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is something like this (pseudocode):

```
<container table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <"300px" table>
    <td>
      <fixed layout table>
```

Basically, split up the table into two tables and have it contained by another table.

Comment: nested tables are best tables

Comment: I know this is pseudocode, but this would be totally awesome as an HTML framework like Pug.js!