# HTML table cells stretching by left column height

Tags: html, html-table

So I have table like this:
http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/5295/1stv.jpg

But I want to do something like this one:
http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/3500/2ndjn.jpg

The left column height isn't fixed. The row number on the right isn't fixed either. All I want that rows on the right would equally streched by left column height and filled the whole gap all way to the bottom, like in my second example.

Comment: any chance that we can use javascript or css here? or only html?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it using `table-layout:fixed`

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed;'>
<tr>
<td>Hello World</td>
<td>Hello World</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hello World</td>
<td>Hello World</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hello World</td>
<td>Hello World</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

then **set some width and height** in your columns and rows as possible

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="0">pic</th>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: auto;
}

td+th {
  width: auto;
}

th {
  height:300px;
}
```

Just change the height of a `th` in the CSS or add different sized pictures to the cell. You may also add a variable number of rows to the HTML.

Note! `rowspan=0` might only work with Firefox and Opera. At least it doesn't work with Safari. You might want to add a picture to the left and two columned table to its right if you do not know the row count beforehand or are not able to use `php` or `JavaScript` to determine it dynamically.

See also this answer: [Table with table-layout: fixed; and how to make one column wider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253963/table-with-table-layout-fixed-and-how-to-make-one-column-wider)